# How to use PyGObject module (gi) on Windows and PyCharm?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pycharm, pygobject

I have Python 3.8.1 installed and I've followed PyGObject [tutorial](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) to install the module.

I've installed MSYS2 64 bits and I certainly can import the gi module using MSYS2 terminal:

[image]

However, if I run Python from the cmd prompt or from PyCharm, it won't work:

[image]

I want to be able to run my project from PyCharm. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the first lines that both Pythons produce. *They are different.*

- The command-line python is a 64-bit version compiled with GCC.
- The Python inside pycharm is a 32-bit version compiled with MSC.

Bottom line: Pycharm is not using the Python that you installed PyGObject in.

---

**Edit**

If you're not using the second Python instance, *and nothing else on your system is using it*, then it is indeed useless.

Having said that, 32-bit programs on windows have a limited adress space (2.5 GiB, IIRC). For data-science projects that might be a significant limitation these days. So I would stick to 64-bit programs these days, unless your PC has less than 4 GiB of RAM. Then it makes sense to run 32-bit software.

Another point is that I've seen reports here on Stackoverflow that Pycharm can interact negatively with Python programs that run inside it. Especially if you are running `multiprocessing`. So you should always test your code from a standalone Python, not from within Pycharm.

Comment: Thank you, I'm currently trying to bind that Python to PyCharm.

Comment: May I ask.. so is the other Python that is compiled with GCC pretty much useless if I'm not using it?